# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6'

Tags: npm, build, yarnpkg, package.json

I've got a problem with my build process in relation to my React app.

I always get the following error:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6'**

if I use this in a polyfill.js:

**import 'core-js/es6';**

That is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.2",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.4.4",
    "eslint": "5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.8.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-string-replace": "^0.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "webpack --colors --profile --progress --env.mode production",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/ --ext .js,.jsx"
  }
}
```

Can someone help here?

Comment: The same error in angular app after upgrade version. Check, if this folder (core-js/es6) exists in your node-modules.

Comment: @KamilNaja I am facing the same problem and the folder (core-js/es6) does not exist in my node_modules, I have (core-js/es) in my node_modules. What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up to have a file named polyfill.js  in **projectpath\src\polyfill.js**
That file only contains this line: **import 'core-js';** this polyfills not only es-6, but is the correct way to use core-js since version 3.0.0.

I added the *polyfill.js* to my webpack-file entry attribute like this:

`entry: ['./src/main.scss', './src/polyfill.js', './src/main.jsx']`

Works perfectly.

I also found some more information here : https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/184

The library author (*zloirock*) claims:

> ES6 changes behaviour almost all features added in ES5, so core-js/es6
>   entry point includes almost all of them. Also, as you wrote, it's
>   required for fixing broken browser implementations.

(Quotation https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/184 from zloirock)

So I think **import 'core-js';** is just fine.

Comment: For additional info on modules & namespaces to import, check the [*core-js* current documentation](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/e88cee56940308d3b4f99251e8f6d96e1ab69401/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md#packages-entry-points-and-modules-names).

Comment: Is it possible to mark this as the correct answer, I think this is more accurate especially almost a year later.

Answer (score 228):

The imports have changed for core-js version 3.0.1 - for example

`import 'core-js/es6/array';`
and 
`import 'core-js/es7/array';`

can now be provided simply by the following

`import 'core-js/es/array';`

if you would prefer not to bring in the whole of core-js

Comment: after migrated angular to 8 I was getting the error but your solution fixed it.

Comment: This is the solution for migration to angular 8 :) thank you

Comment: I have nothing in my code that starts with `import 'core-js/...` so what should I change and where? Using VueJS 2

Comment: @volumeone run 'npm i core-js' in your terminal.

Comment: @ShivamShukla thanks but I had to downgrade to 2.6.11 for it to work. There is a bug between mini-css-extract-plugin and core-js 3

Answer (score 129):

I found possible answer. You have *core-js* version 3.0, and this version doesn't have separate folders for *ES6* and *ES7*; that's why the application cannot find correct paths.

To resolve this error, you can downgrade the *core-js* version to 2.5.7. This version produces correct catalogs structure, with separate *ES6* and *ES7* folders.

To downgrade the version, simply run:

```
npm i -S core-js@2.5.7
```

In my case, with Angular, this works ok.

Comment: Thanks, that's a solution at least. I also found the solution to use version 3.0 without downgrading. Will post

Comment: Can you explain how downgrading doesn't break everything else and why you wouldn't just update to a new format? You've got a tonne of upvotes which suggests this is working well for people but surely this isn't a good long term solution.

Comment: So, perfect solutions is upgrade your imports whenever you use core-js to use newest version. Unfortunately, when this dependency is used in other library, this solution can be impossible and you need use workaround.

Comment: -1 This is a band-aid to get rid of the message, downgrading your packages is not a good practice to get in to. Readers are much better off with correcting their imports. Not only is it *just as simple* if not more simple, it is far better practice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56186570/610573

Comment: This works but does it mean I cannot use core-js 3? People say "upgrade your imports" to what exactly? I don't have any code that says `import 'core-js/es6'` in my own code. Maybe some node_modules do but I don't want to tamper with third-party packages surely...

Comment: npm install --save core-js@^2.5.0, worked for me, thanks

Comment: Upgrading your packages isn't always the solution. Just because it's the latest doesn't mean that other packages you use also support it. The gordion knot is ridiculous to always keep up to date.

Comment: This is probably a framework hell :D LOL. Downgrade `core-js` and all errors are gone like a magic.

Answer (score 53):

Change all "es6" and "es7" to "es" in your polyfills.ts and polyfills.ts (Optional).

- From: `import 'core-js/es6/symbol';`
- To: `import 'core-js/es/symbol';`

Answer (score 51):

After Migrated to **New Angular Version** or Version changed for **core-js**, `core-js/es6` or `core-js/es7` Will not work.

You have to simply replace import `core-js/es/` in your polyfills.ts file.

For ex.

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol'
```

to

```
import 'core-js/es/symbol'
```

This will work properly.

Comment: Works for me in Angular 8!

Comment: This works for me but I'm still super confused. I cross referenced with Angular source expecting to see this newer single import - and even the 'hello world Ivy' example still shows `/es6` paths https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/integration/cli-hello-world-ivy-minimal/src/polyfills.ts Any idea why they're doing that?

Comment: More details in issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32228

Comment: you are a life saver!

Comment: This works exactly as advertised. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

[image: Make changes to your Polyfills.ts file]

Change all `es6` and `es7` to `es` in your `polyfills.ts`

example:

```js
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

becomes

```js
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
```

Comment: Thanks, after adding all mentioned imports my app is now working on IE11.

Comment: This works exactly as advertised. Kudos!

Answer (score 14):

If you use `@babel/preset-env` and `useBuiltIns`, then you just have to add `corejs: 3` beside the useBuiltIns option, to specify which version to use, default is `corejs: 2`.

```
presets: [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env", {
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "corejs": 3
    }
  ]
],
```

For further details see: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md#babelpreset-env

Comment: Worked just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Sure, I had a similar issue and a simple

```
npm uninstall @babel/polyfill --save &&
npm install @babel/polyfill --save
```

did the trick for me.

However, usage of @babel/polyfill is deprecated (according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308769/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-core-js-es6/56433261#comment100711989_56433261)) so only try this if you think you have older packages installed or if all else fails.

Comment: Dude you're a life saver. It drove me freaking nuts.

Comment: Usage of `@babel/polyfill` is deprecated.

Comment: I am upgrading from Angular 13 to 14 and this worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I got this error today (**13 April 2022**) after upgrade `core-js` version from 2 to 3 and after I tried to find the answer for several Hour, finally I can solved it after update my `babel.config.js` and make it like this:

**Before:**

```
presets: [ "@vue/app" ]
```

**After:**

```
presets: [ [ "@vue/app", { useBuiltIns: "entry" } ] ]
```

**Notes**

1. I'm using Vue in my project
2. I already try almost all question regarding `npm uninstall core-js` and tried to re-install it again `npm install core-js --save` or `delete node_modules, package-lock.json, and yarn-lock.json` but still failed to solved it
3. I can solved it if I downgrade `core-js` version using this line : `npm install core-js@2.6.5`, but it is not a good solution for long term condition
4. Explanation for this problem: this problem happens because the path for `core-js/es6` in version 3 is already changed to `core-js/es` that's why your project can't find it the right path for the directory where it pointed to `core-js/es6`

Comment: Cheers buddy. You definitely saved me a day or two of debugging this crap.

Answer (score 5):

Just change "target": "es2015" to "target": "es5" in your tsconfig.json.

Work for me with Angular 8.2.XX

Tested on IE11 and Edge

Answer (score 1):

It is vital that Webpack is able to resolve the import statements prepended to source files by Babel, for example

```
import "core-js/modules/es.object.freeze.js";
```

If such an import statement is inserted into a file which does not reside in a package which has core-js as a dependency, then Webpack may not be able to resolve its location on disk, resulting in a ModuleNotFoundError.

The solution for me was to specify the application's node_modules directory in the `resolve` section of my webpack.config.cjs:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"), // Contains core-js.
            "node_modules"                        // Webpack's default.
        ]
    }
}
```

And of course core-js is listed as a dependency in my application's package.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^3.19.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 14 I had to run `npm i --save core-js`

I kept the polyfills the same as in the [Amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/angular/#internet-explorer-11-ie11-support):

```
import 'core-js/es/typed-array';
import 'core-js/es/object';
```

Answer (score 0):

`npx yarn add @babel/runtime@>=7 core-js-pure@>=3`
by installing this, resolved my issue

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The imports have changed now this resolved my issue :)
Change all "es6" and "es7" to "es" in your polyfills.ts
**From**:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
```

**To this**:

```
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
```

This issue I faced on migration from 7 to 8 transition of angular update