# IE 11 not loading Angular 10 app after recommended fixes

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, angular10

I've gone with the standard fix for IE11 issues with Angular 10 apps (not loading fonts, script errors for certain characters in the bundled files) -- by adding a *tsconfig-es5.app.json* file with a target of *es5* and I've added the *es5* entry in the *configurations* object. And the *polyfills.ts* is importing the *classlist.js* file. There's nothing I've missed. Here's my package.json file with the build and run scripts I use:

You can see that both the *dev:es5* and *dev:internal:es5* have configs of *es5*. Now here's my *angular.json* file build configuration:

```
"build": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                "options": {
                    "aot": true,
                    "outputPath": "dist/{MyContent}/",
                    "index": "src/index.html",
                    "main": "src/main.ts",
                    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                    "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                    "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
                    "scripts": []
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                        "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "{myEnvDevFile}",
                                "with": "{myEnvProdFile}                               }
                        ],
                        "optimization": true,
                        "outputHashing": "none",
                        "sourceMap": false,
                        "extractCss": true,
                        "namedChunks": false,
                        "aot": true,
                        "extractLicenses": true,
                        "vendorChunk": false,
                        "buildOptimizer": true,
                        "budgets": [
                            {
                                "type": "initial",
                                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                "maximumError": "5mb"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "es5": {
                        "budgets": [
                            {
                                "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                            }
                        ],
                        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here's my original *tsconfig.app.json* file:

```
 {
       "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
        "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
       "types": []
   },
   "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
   "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
  }
```

And finally the *tsconfig-es5.app.json* file:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

I don't think I've missed anything at all. The Angular CLI is 10 so I think I'm good. Have I made a glaring error?

To me, I must missing a polyfill in polyfill.ts but I don't know which one. both zone.js and classlist.js are being imported.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please follow the below steps to run `Angular 10` app in IE11.**

Step 1 :: Check this URL ([medium.com](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920)) and do as it is mentioned. If you are lucky then your app will work on IE11, if not then follow Step 2.

Step 2 :: You may get below error in the terminal -

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/reflect' in '...\src'
```

Then you have to comment out `import 'core-js/es6/reflect'` and add below code in `polyfills.ts` -

```
/** Evergreen browsers require these. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. */
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
```

Ref URL for Step 2 - [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308769/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-core-js-es6)

[image: Angular10-in-IE11]