# Module not found: Can't resolve './datepicker'

Tags: react-native, datepicker, expo, tcomb-form-native

I've got this error message when I am trying to run the command "expo start --web"

Failed to compile.
G:/Just Build/rn/hello/tenten/node_modules/tcomb-form-native/lib/templates/bootstrap/index.js
**Module not found: Can't resolve './datepicker'** in 'G:\Just Build\rn\hello\tenten\node_modules\tcomb-form-native\lib\templates\bootstrap'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308769/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-core-js-es6)